# Hide toolbar and show colors

Tags: ckeditor

I have a problem. I'd like to show CKEditor without toolbar, and still keep colors on it. This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textAreaName = 'description';
    CKEDITOR.replace( textAreaName, {
        removePlugins: 'toolbar,elementspath',
        readOnly: true
    } ) ;

    var oCKeditor = CKEDITOR.instances[textAreaName];
});
```

The problem is text color doesn't show. It seems that CKEditor disable color as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep colors on it"? If it is invisible, so how can it be in any color?

Comment: Edited, removed uiColor. I mean hide the toolbar but still show colors n textarea.

Comment: Why do you use an instance of CKEditor without toolbars and in readonly state? Isn't it easier to put that content in a div?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (because it's still unclear) that you want to keep text color in editor's contents (BTW. editor's contents is not rendered using `textarea` - it is only used for easier data submitting) this is a solution:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'span{!color}';
```

This will allow `span` elements with `color` style. Read more about [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

Comment: I mean hiding toolbar but the text content still have colors, not filtering.

Answer (score 0):

use this `config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';`

Where config is object of that component.